# How do I turn “select all data-tab-targets” into jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`const tabs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tab-target]");`

I then loop through the tab targets `tabs.forEach(tab`

I'm unsure how to grab all the data-tab-targets with jquery and then loop through all the individual tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-tab-target]').each(function(){
   var tab = $(this);
  //...do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
const tabs = $("[data-tab-target]");

tabs.each(function (index, tab) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(tab);
});

// using arrow function
tabs.each((index, tab) => {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(tab);
});

// specific attribute
var target = $("[data-tab-target='1']");

// using for loop
for (var tab of Array.from(tabs)) {
  console.log(tab);
}

for (var tab of [...tabs]) {
  console.log(tab);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-tab-target="1">1</div>
<div data-tab-target="2">2</div>
<div data-tab-target="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-tab-target]').each(function(index) { 
    console.log(index);
    // Do something here 
};
```

Jquery each function iterates through each of the DOM elements picked up by the query, you can then do something with each of these values.

$.each: https://api.jquery.com/each/